# (air pressure and displacement) Isn't this image wrong?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, waves, acoustics, pressure

[image]

Isn't this figure wrong? P(x,t) = -B(dy/dx) . If the derivative of air displacement has a maximum, then this is where the pressure is minimum, not maximum as this figure suggests. Could someone clarify this for me? Thanks.

If anything this is the source for the image: http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/waves/standw.html

y(x,t) is the function for displacement.

B is the bulk modulus

P(x,t) is the function for pressure.

Answer (score 1):

It depends on the direction in which you choose the $y$-axis. If a positive $y$ means a displacement to the *left*, when this figure is accurate. But you right, that choice is at least unconventional and should have been indicated in the figure.